# javascript onclick function with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

For example i have a `<P>`tag contain a class as below

```
<p class="badge">new</p>
```

and i do like to add some CSS for the element, when  the user `.onclick()`, so i created a function like below

```
 $(".badge").click(function(){
    $(".badge").css("display","none");
});
```

And the question is how may i use cookies to remember that the user had already clicked before, so the css will be added automatically?

Comment: you can store it in local storage and retrieve it on load

Comment: i only know to store cookies by string like document.cookie = "username=jack";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off using `window.localStorage`

```
 $(".badge").click(function(){
    $(".badge").css("display","none");
    localStorage.setItem('btnClicked', true);
 });
```

And on document load you should check if the user has clicked the button before and act accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var clicked = localStorage.getItem("btnClicked");
    if(clicked){
       $(".badge").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [jQuery cookie library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):-

> Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
> ```
>
> Read cookie:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name'); // => "value"
> ```

So your code could work like:-

```js
$(".badge").click(function(){
    $(".badge").css("display","none");
    $.cookie('hide-badge', true, { expires: 7 });
});

$(function(){
  
  if($.cookie('hide-badge'))
    $(".badge").css("display","none");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<p class="badge">new</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cookies, try this sample:

```
$(function() {

    function getCookie(name) {

        var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
        ));
        return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }

    $('.badge').click(function(){

        var 
            cookieValue = +getCookie('counter'); // get cookie

        $('.badge').css('display' ,'none');

        document.cookie = 'counter=' + (cookieValue + 1); // setting a new value
    });

});
```

But, as noticed **@guradio**, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to do that:

```
$(function() {

    $('.badge').click(function(){

        var 
            counter = +localStorage['counter']; // get counter's value from localStorage

        $('.badge').css('display' ,'none');

        localStorage['counter'] = (counter + 1) // setting a new value
    });

});
```

localStorage makes your code more compact an elegant :)

> The Web Storage API provides mechanisms by which browsers can store
>   key/value pairs, **in a much more intuitive fashion than using cookies**.
>
> The two mechanisms within Web Storage are as follows:
>
> - **sessionStorage** maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long
>     as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores)
> - **localStorage** does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

`sessionStorage` is similar to `localStorage`, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends.